# Debugging and profiling directx 9 calls?

Tags: debugging, virtual-functions

Lets say I'm debugging a game which I don't have the src code. This game was built with directx 9 and I want to dig into the more low-level stuff around it. I already did some hooks in some dx9 calls such as Present and EndScene to create some nice stuff for the game but I was wondering how people debug this kind of scenario in "real life". As almost every dx9 function is a virtual function of a class the analysis of it gets very hard very fast (at least for me) and I find myself lost don't knowing where exactly the functions are being called without debugging, etc. Another thing I was wondering is if it's possible to profile the dx9 calls to know some bottlenecks and stuff.

Any kind of help will be very appreciated here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've used IDA for this, it has ability to load VTBL structures and apply them to the assembler code. So, I could see "call [IDirect3DSurface9.LockRect]" instead of "call dword ptr [edx + 0x64]"

Comment: I`ll take a look at this in a moment, thanks for replying!